# While loop making even/odd blocks with uneven number. Hard code second block

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Probably my title is hard to understand, if you can make it more clear for everyone please edit my post thankyou.

So what i did i created a while loop and wanted the blocks going like a X

I have two blocks aside eachother everytime. But i want this `X` form.
So it will be `(block 1) [gray] , (block 2) [darkgray]`
and then going `(block 1) [darkgray] , (block 2) [gray]`. In order to achieve this i made inside my while loop a if function and before the if i created a `counter++`.
Counter starts at 0 and adds 1 till it gets too 3, because the 3 makes it uneven it will make this X form. But the problem is that the first two blocks will remain gray because of the uneven number 3 at the early on.

Does anyone know how i maybe could hardcode the first two blocks ?.

Also in my code i'm taking the information out of the database in a Descending order.

Its created in wordpress but its more about the php function i made here.

```
It has to be. 
First = Gray
Second = Dark Gray
Third = Dark Gray
Fourth = Gray.
```

And this should repeat itself whole the time.

```
enter code here
```

The code that is already been made(because the code is made in a different language i removed it and replaced with comments for easier understanding) :

```
      global $wp_query;
      $temp = $wp_query; 
      $args = (array(
              'post_type' => 'news',
              'posts_per_page' => 9999,
             'post__not_in' => array(835),
             'order' => 'DESC'));
            $wp_query = new WP_Query();
       $counter = 0;
      $wp_query->query($args); 
      while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : 
           $wp_query->the_post(); 
      ?>
      <?php $counter ++; 
      if($counter == 3) { ?>
       /** here comes the dark gray block **/
     <?php $counter = 0; ?>
     <?php }else { ?>
      /** here comes the gray block **/
     <?php } ?>
```

So after alot of help of the community i found my the solution in the end. I feel so stupid that i did not found this out myself. Using this method you will obtain the (Block 1 = Gray),(Block 2 = Dark Gray),(Block 3 = Gray),(Block 4 = Dark Gray). 
**Solution**

```
 <?php $counter ++; 
  if($counter == 1) { ?>
   /** here comes the gray block **/
 <?php }else if($counter == 2 { ?>
  /** here comes the dark gray block **/
 <?php }else if($counter == 3 { ?>
  /** here comes the gray block **/
 <?php }else if($counter === 4 { ?>
  /** here comes the dark gray block **/
 <?php $counter = 0; } ?>
```

So what i did here in the end is i create the 4 first coloring manual and then i reset it just back to zero and let it loop this. since i have a row of two blocks everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple use **modulo**

`%` is modulo operator.

```
<?php
for($counter=0; $counter<10; ++$counter)
echo (!($counter % 3)  ? "gray" : "dark gray").'<br>'; 
?>
```

It outputs

```
gray
dark gray
dark gray
gray
dark gray
dark gray
gray
dark gray
dark gray
gray
```

As you wanted.

I've created fiddle to show you how it works.

[Check fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pa2-s5j)

Comment: Hi Robert, 
What i want is 

First = Gray
Second = Dark Gray
Third = Dark Gray
Fourth = Gray

Comment: @WesleyCheung check updated version. I've also created fiddle. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/up3-z6e

Comment: I checked the phpfiddle and i see that it does 1. Gray 2. Gray 3. Dark Gray. That is what i already have.
It should be 1. Gray 2. Dark Gray 3. Dark Gray 4. Gray

Comment: Thank you soo much. I'm still having a problem. 
The setup of my blocks is [1] [2] (new row) [3] [4] and so on. it has to be [1] - gray , [2] - dark gray , [3] dark gray , [4] gray but eventually at number 7-8 i get two blocks that are both dark gray. can you help me with this one please?

Comment: I don't understand you want 1 block gray then 2 dark gray and 1 gray and 2 dark gray right? Put some kind of array how it should look like.

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bn3-pcf ignore the for loop you created. see below the at the echo. This is how it needs to be. Still havent figured out how. I though if i tell the first 4 it should work.

Comment: @WesleyCheung I've changed it again. Output is exactly as you wanted. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/a3e-id0

Comment: amazing job, but in the end i figured out myself... that code of yours sure does create what i desired but you have to manually type in the propers before this works good. If you want to know how i made the solution see my post above. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 4):

instead of using conditions put all the content in parent div and place css for childs like this

```
<div class="PARENT_DIV">
     while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
      ?>
      <div id="CHILD_DIV">
         YOUR CONTENT 
      </div>
     <?php } ?>
</div>

<style>
    .PARENT_DIV:nth-child(odd){ background-color:#eee; }
    .PARENT_DIV:nth-child(even){ background-color:#fff; }
</style>
```

Comment: Note: Does not work in older versions of IE (which can be fixed using Javascript). If you do not care about IE, or if most of your users do not use it, then this is a good solution. It is part of the presentation (and not the programming logic), so using CSS is a good idea.

Comment: I think CSS3 works fine for IE9 but if you have to focus on version below this than you have to use javascript as told by @Sverri M. Olsen..

Comment: This is the zebra stripe. 
It will do repeat block 1 to be gray and block 2 to be gray. but i want it to keep switching from gray, darkgray. dark gray,gray

Comment: do you want gray, darkgray,darkgray,gray, darkgray,darkgray,gray, darkgray,darkgray, like this or somthing else...please give the chain for color

Comment: @WesleyCheung it possible to give any combination of colors for child by placing proper value for n. Check this url to get more about choosing child through css http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: @RajuJain the chain of colour should be gray,darkgray,darkgray,gray
Thank you!, yes i have heard about the nth child. But i need to find a code that doesn't generate it based on css3. It has to be compatitble on browser without support of css3. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this also

```
$colour = "gray";

while (//loop though posts){

$colour = ($colour=="gray")?"darkgray":"gray";
//do something with colour
```

This needs no extra counter, It just uses the colour variable

This uses the Ternary operator 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: The code is wrong. Have you checked it? There is no Ternary operator you missed `?` in statement.

Comment: Updated now. Had an extra : instead of ?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have the right ideas but manage to make Zebra stripes, which is not what you asked for. This is a simple solution to show how it works, you need to modify it to suit your style.

I put the colours in an array and then use the modulus operator but with a base of 4 which will return the value of 0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1... inside your loop. Use that as an index into the array to get the colour.

```
$colours = array("gray","darkgray","darkgray","gray");

$counter = 0;

while (condition) {
    $colour = $colours[$counter % 4];
    //your code here

    $counter++;
}
```